# Add CKEditor in Laravel 8 via Composer

Tags: php, laravel, npm, ckeditor, laravel-8

I am trying to add CKEditor into my project using composer, and I am using Laravel 8.

when I run the following command:

```
$ composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
```

I get the following errors.

```
Using version ^4.7 for unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update unisharp/laravel-ckeditor
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires unisharp/laravel-ckeditor ^4.7 -> satisfiable by unisharp/laravel-ckeditor[4.7.2].
    - unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

This following image shows the content of the `composer.json` file.

[image: Root composer.json requires unisharp/laravel-ckeditor ^4.7 -> satisfiable by unisharp/laravel-ckeditor[4.7.2]]

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall the Composer CKEditor-related packages. Secondly, add the [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html) NPM package.

```
npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

**app.js**

```
const ClassicEditor = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' );

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

Now, do a build.

```
npm run prod
```

In your Blade file, add the following.

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Before the final `</body>` tag add:

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Step 2: could you give some details about the app.js file please ?? am  I going to create it or it's an existing file somewhere??